# How to determine which multiple key binding is being fired

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery:

```
$("input[name='first'], input[name='second'], 
input[name='third']").bind("keypress", function(e) {

      //how to determine which input is being entered

});
```

I have 3 inputs field,
I wanted to know how to distinguish and determine which input value is 'on typing' based on above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use the key word `this`

```
$("input[name='first'], input[name='second'], input[name='third']").bind("keypress", function(e) {
console.log(this);
alert(this.name); 
});
```

[**working fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/09wmffta/7/)